# How to register for and consume server sent events from IEX Cloud?

Tags: java, spring

After reading documentation from IEX and researching online, I am stuck in understanding how to register and consume SSE events from IEX Cloud.

I want to consume events in my Java backend, map data into a POJO, analyze/manipulate the data, and ultimately display the final results on a frontend app.

Right now, I have a scheduled service that runs every minute but I prefer the efficiency of SSE Events given its streaming nature.

Additionally, I need to re-establish terminated connections as fast as possible.

IEX Cloud documentation provides the following endpoint for interval streaming `https://cloud-sse.iexapis.com/stable/stocksUSNoUTP1Minute?token=YOUR_TOKEN&symbols={symbol}&token=SECRET_TOKEN`. However, I can't find any examples of how to implement this and I am completely new to SSE Events.